# Printing character from register

Tags: printing, character, nasm

I'm using the NASM assembler.

The value returned to the eax register is supposed to be a character, when I attempt to print the integer representation its a value that looks like a memory address. I was expecting the decimal representation of the letter. For example, if character 'a' was moved to eax I should see 97 being printed (the decimal representation of 'a'). But this is not the case.

```
section .data
             int_format db "%d", 0
;-----------------------------------------------------------

mov eax, dword[ebx + edx]
push eax
push dword int_format
call _printf   ;prints a strange number
add esp, 8

xor eax, eax
mov eax, dword[ebx + edx]
push eax
call _putchar ;prints the correct character!
add esp, 4
```

So what gives here? ultimately I want to compare the character so it is important that eax gets the correct decimal representation of the character.

Answer (score 2):

```
mov eax, dword[ebx + edx]
```

You are loading a dword (32 bits) from the address pointed to ebx+edx. If you want a single character, you need to load a byte. For that, you can use movzx instruction:

```
movzx eax, byte[ebx + edx]
```

This will load a single byte to the low byte of `eax` (i.e. `al`) and zero out the rest of the register.

Another option would be to mask out the extra bytes after loading the dword, e.g.:

```
and eax, 0ffh
```

or

```
movxz eax, al
```

As for `putchar`, it works because it interprets the passed value as char, i.e. it ignores the high three bytes present in the register and considers only the low byte.

Comment: Thanks alot, that worked beautifully. I was curious about the dword move but the movzx was totally over my head, I read up on the instruction. It makes sense now. First time doing assembly, thanks again!!